# Need help in making - Member can only use a command in a ticket channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const tChannel = member.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === `ticket-${mAuthor.username}`)
```

I want the message.author to be able to only use that command in their ticket channel.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information to go on it seems that you want to check the channel anytime a member uses that command. The simple solution would be to have a `map` keyed on user ID with the value being the channel ID that is theirs. Something like:

```
bot.on("message", function(message){
    const userChannelID = channelMap[message.author.id]
    if(userChannelID === message.channel.name){
        //Execute command here
    }
    else{
        message.channel.send("You are not authorized to use this command in this channel")
    }
}
```